# No visible @interface for 'GIDSignIn' declares the selector 'handleURL:

Tags: ios, objective-c, gidsignin

I implemented the delegate method of Google SignIn in objective C. But I am getting the below error `Error - No visible @interface for 'GIDSignIn'`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options{

    return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this and try again once , ref : [Google Sign-In quick migration guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide)

```
  [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
```

full answer

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

change from:

```
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                       annotation:annotation];
```

to:

```
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url];
```

go to: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide#objective-c